# Accessing a specific class attribute within an index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-development

I made a basic Python RPG game , and I'm attempting to recreate it with object-oriented programming. My goal is to have each battle scene capable of importing a character class object with a given amount of health and a list of attacks it can use, and an enemy object with health and a list of attacks it can use as well. However, I've run into a dead end when attempting to make the battle system utilize the movelist of the player class. Here is the code I have written:

```
import random

class Class:
    def __init__(self, name, health, attacklist):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.attacklist = attacklist

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, name, health, attacklist):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.attacklist = attacklist

class Attack:
    def __init__(self, name, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage

Punch = Attack("Punch", 50)
Bite = Attack("Punch", 25)

fighter_attacklist = [Punch]
rat_attacklist = [Bite]

Fighter = Class("Fighter", 500, fighter_attacklist)
Rat = Enemy("Rat", 100, rat_attacklist)

enemy_list = [Rat]

while True:
    print("Choose your class:")
    choice = input()
    if choice == "1":
        player_class = Fighter
        print("You have chosen:", player_class.name)
        player_attacklist = player_class.attacklist
        enemy = random.choice(enemy_list)
        print("Your enemy is:", enemy.name)
    else:
        print("Error, invalid input!")
        continue
    while True:
        print("Your health:", player_class.health)
        print("Enemy health:", enemy.health)
        player_move = input()
        if player_move == "1":
            player_damage = player_class.attacklist[0]
            print(player_damage)
```

My goal is to have the damage dealt by the player subtracted from the enemy health, thus successfully completing the "attack." However, I'm stumped by how to get the player_damage to equal the "damage" attribute of the "Punch" "Attack" from the "Fighter" class. I'm sorry if what I'm writing is confusing, I hope someone can understand what I'm trying to accomplish here and has a suggestion for my code. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So first, you're attacklist variable attached to the player_class object contains objects, not integers. (Note, change the name of the Class class to something else.  It's not good practice to use names one keystroke off of a keyword!  Maybe RPGClass?  Makes it a little more distinguishable.)

```
# Wrong, returns an object of the Attack class  
player_damage = player_class.attacklist[0]

# Correct, returns the damage value of the Attack class
player_damage = player_class.attacklist[0].damage
```

The damage variable of the Attack object is probably what you are trying to retrieve.  However, if you are dead set on calling the damage value by calling the object itself, we can also add this following method to the Attack class!

```
class Attack:
    def __init__(self, name, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.damage = damage
    # Add a __repr__ method
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.damage)
```

Now, whenever the object itself is called upon, it will return a string of the damage variable!  Do note that **repr** should return a string, so if you need to calculate with the value, cast it to integer: int(variable)

Additionally, I would not suggest using **repr** for this.  **repr** is usually used to reconstruct an object by returning the arguments used to construct it.  Between these two, I would go with the first solution.

If we want to be really neat with our code, we would actually forgo the two previous solutions provided and instead create a method for the Class class.  Encapsulation is the key when programming!  Python does away with a lot of this because it assumes that the coder knows what is safe and not, but the style that results from using encapsulation looks really nice and a lot more readable!  So, let's add a method to the Class class that returns us the Attack Damage from a provided argument.  After all, directly accessing the list just to retrieve a value is not a safe practice!

```
class Class:
    def __init__(self, name, health, attacklist):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.attacklist = attacklist
    def get_damage(self, attack_index):
        if attack_index < 0 or attack_index >= len(self.attacklist):
            raise RuntimeError("attack_index is not valid! " + str(attack_index))
        return self.attacklist[attack_index].damage
```

Now we can use this method to retrieve the damage safely!

```
player_damage = player_class.get_damage(0)
```